# Angular 2 ADAL wait for service.init

Tags: angular, adal

Since AdalService.init(config); returns void and thus you cannot follow it with a .then(), how do you wait for authentication to complete before making some other call?

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to wait for the authentication. The normal progress for calling the web API which protect by Azure AD is like below:

1. users navigate to the app
2. OP click the button to login with Azure AD
3. Users navigate to the page which protected by Azure AD
4. The page we can get the access token for the protecting resource and show it to the users.

I also update a code sample to calling Microsoft Graph from angular2 app from [here](https://github.com/VitorX/Angular2-MicrosoftGraph-AcquireToken).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using something like ng2-adal(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-adal) with authguard feature in Angular 2. If you don't want to pull in ng2-adal you can write your own wrapper around the adal library. Basically in the can activate of Authguard you give something like :-

```
  if (this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.adalService.login();
      return false;
    }
```

It would be nice to have a common http gatweay for your whole project and you check there the same code to see if adal is authenticated before making any calls .The ng2-adal already takes care of this stuff. Refer to the source code if you want to implement it with observables by yourself
https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal/blob/master/src/services/adal.service.ts
https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal/blob/master/src/services/authHttp.service.ts